# Windows: Command-line method to know the name of my audio recording device(s)?

Tags: command-line, audio

> I don't know if this could be a rather programming question, so I have
>   opened a corresponding (and a bit different) question at
>   [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30563471/windows-shell-how-can-i-get-the-audio-devices-names). I will post the answer here if I obtain it, by the
>   way.

I need to **get the name of the available recording** devices for my Windows (`SoundMAX HD Audio I` in this example):

[image: Audio recording device example]

But I need to do it **via command-line** if possible, as long as I normally connect to the computer(s) via **remote terminal** (SSH) console.

How could I solve this?

I need methods for **both Windows XP and Vista** (and laters), but at least for Vista.
**Additional software** allowed. Open Source preferred, but not mandatory.

Comment: Only on XP or newer versions too? Are you restricted to only what is installed by default or can you use third-party programs?

Comment: Edited to reflect, @Karan .

Comment: Turns out this is not so easy (at least as far as i can tell). Found something for Vista+ but not for XP. Even for Vista+ it's all there in the registry but I'm still trying to figure out how the default device can be identified. If that is known then a third-party utility won't be required. WMIC unfortunately was no help.

Comment: Well, @Karan, maybe I wasn't clear enough: there is no need to know which one the **default** device could be. Just listing the name of **all** the recording devices would be fine. I have edited the title of the original question to fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Vista and above only: Download [SoundVolumeView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sound_volume_view.html) (free and portable but not open-source) and use it along with the following batch file:

```
SoundVolumeView /scomma Audio.txt
for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%d in ('type Audio.txt ^| find "Capture"') do @echo Default recording device is: "%%d"
```

---

In Windows 7 the REG_SZ string value named **{a45c254e-df1c-4efd-8020-67d146a850e0},2** under each `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Capture\{GUID}\Properties` key contains the name of the corresponding recording/capture device registered on the system.

You can retrieve all the recording/capture device names as follows:

```
for /f "tokens=9 delims=\" %a in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Capture" /s ^| find "\Properties"') do @for /f "tokens=2*" %k in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Capture\%a\Properties" /v "{a45c254e-df1c-4efd-8020-67d146a850e0},2"') do @echo "%l"
```

Comment: I don't have access to XP right now to check its registry, nor to Vista to confirm whether the registry locations are the same as above. Should not be difficult to locate them though.

Comment: I have access to both XP and 7. I am seeking for a method to guess the GUID right now...

Comment: See if my latest edit helps.

Comment: Your `tokens=9...`  line generates many (50+) device names on Windows 7: Conector, Rear, Side... etc. I get the important one, named "Micrófono" (my Windows is in spanish), but the real name is cutted; FFMPEG yields `Micrófono (Realtek High Definit` for the same device (name cutted too, but this time at 32 chars). See here for your code: http://pastebin.com/RszV3pYN . And here for FFMPEG output for the same computer: http://pastebin.com/btv2mQV3 . My test to validate: VLC command line streaming; it works with the long name (FFMPEG), but it seems not to be working with the short (your code)one.

Comment: And here is the output for your `SoundVolumeView` code: http://pastebin.com/UxdzwjLy . I think FFMPEG is still our best bet. Maybe the `SoundVolumeView` method could be enhanced?

Comment: Try the edited command now. I'll fix the SoundVolumeView one too.

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/snBenQZf . Names are longer now, indeed. But `Micrófono` (note the spanish character `ó` sometimes is wrong, but that is not a problem, as long as I can correct it if I know the rest of the name) keeps too short.

Comment: I renamed my Microphone (in Win7 you can do that) to "Microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)" and my edited command above shows it fully, and BTW so does the SoundVolumeView code. The `ó` problem is because cmd doesn't support Unicode by default. Typing `chcp 65001` before running the commands might help.

Comment: Mmm... I think your method is correct too. Note here: http://picpaste.com/Audio_recording_device_-_Microphone-dAqRwbW2.PNG . Both the short and the long name (with the `Realtek...` part) seem to be correct. Your answer is OK. Thanks you.

Comment: The `chcp 65001` on Windows shell did not change anything about the `ó` character. Maybe another code page could do it? I am not using PowerShell, but the classic console.

Comment: Yes, I'm using cmd too. On Win7 at least why don't you simply rename your Microphone to a short and simple "Microphone"? Other than that I don't know what else to suggest. If ffmpeg does what you want on all your target OSes then it might be best for you to use that.

Comment: The `chcp 65001` does neither work on remote SSH console (I am using Bitvise SSH Server).

Comment: Renaming is not always a possibility. For example, when accesing the computer remotely via text console (telnet or SSH). Anyway, your method to detect audio recording devices is preferred for me, as long as FFMPEG requires (or so I think) .NET (at least for v4.8 and above), and is a bigger (more than 20MB) program. Scripting rulez! :-)

Comment: "Renaming is not always a possibility." - True, especially when the remote PC is not under your control.

Comment: Indeed. Or under Windows XP. Or under a non-privileged user account. Or in scripting cases. Whenever local or remote.